# bitWrite function with a pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, arduino

I'm new to arduino and it's programing language. I learnt that we can't have methods returning arrays, but we can use pointers as an alternative.

So I have this method:

```
byte SUM(byte A, byte B, bool Cyi, byte *sum, bool *Cyo)
{
  bool d0;
  bool d1;

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
  {
    d0 = bitRead(A,i);
    d1 = bitRead(B,i);
    bitWrite(*sum,i,d0 ^ d1 ^ Cyi);
    *Cyo = d0 && d1 || Cyi && (d0 ^ d1);
    Cyi = Cyo;
  }
}
```

I'am new to pointers but I guess the problem here is that bitWrite method does not accept a pointer? I don't know what do to next and I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you told use what the problem is. Does it not compile? If so whats the error. Does it not run? ...

Comment: Wild guess, you should use bitWrite(sum, without "*".

Comment: @user1034749 [maybe not](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitWrite), but I'm also not sure.

Comment: `*Cyo = d0 && d1 + Cyi && (d0 ^ d1);` here `+` has higher precedence over `&&`, so are you sure what you're doing?

Comment: @NatashaDutta As I said I'am new to Arduino, it was supposed "+" to be "||"

Comment: If I leave it like this will compile, but If I try to sum 1 + 2 the result is 253. And now I just upvoted the right answer, that's why the sum was wrong :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adruino is not a programming language but a microcontroler platform for which you could write code in c.

you wrote in your code:

```
   Cyi = Cyo;
```

but Cyi is of type "bool" and Cyo a type of "bool *" correct it with

```
   Cyi = *Cyo;
```

Comment: Goddamit I was so focused in learning pointers and trying to figure out what was going on that I completly forgot this... There are times I just want to hang myself, thanks a lot